# Como enviar un id desde vue.js a ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, entity-framework, asp.net-core, axios

En un proyecto con **vue.js** y **entity framework**, la cosa es que debo traer la información de una medición dependiendo del `id` que le envié, pero al enviar a llamar el dato, me trae todas las mediciones, es decir me trae todos los arreglos, no se, si es que no le envió bien el datos.

Vale recalcar que trabajo con **axios** para los tramites por `http`, y creo que se lo envió mal, ya que si entro directo a el *asp*. enviándole un `id` al url, si me hace la búsqueda.

este es en método para mandar el `id`, el cual me trae todas las mediciones:

```
 Actualizar(idMedicion) {
  let me = this;
  axios
    .get("api/MedicionPrincipals/" , idMedicion )
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      me.medi = response.data;
     me.nise = me.medi.nise

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
},
```

Este es el de **asp.net** pero si me sirve correctamente:

```
    //GET: api/Transformadors/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult GetMedicion(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var medicion = _context.MedicionPrincipal
                .Include(m => m.IdClienteNavigation)//traigo los datos del cliente
                .Include(m => m.IdUsuarioNavigation)// traigo los datos del usuario
                .Include(m => m.Movimiento)// traigo los datos del movimiento
                .Include(m => m.Medidor)//traigo los datos de medidor
                .Include(m => m.Medidor.MedidorInstalado)// traigo la tabla medidor instalado
                .Include(m => m.Medidor.MedidorRetirado)// traigo la tabla medidor retirado
                .Include(m => m.Medidor.MedidorRespaldo)// traigo la tabla medidor retirado
                .Include(m => m.Medidor.Totalizado)// traigo la tabla totalizado
                .Include(m => m.Medidor.Transformador)// traigo la tabla transformador
                .Include(m => m.Medidor.Transformador)// traigo la tabla transformador
                .Include(m => m.Medidor.Transformador.TransfPotencial)// traigo la tabla transformador
                .Include(m => m.Medidor.Transformador.TransfCorriente)// traigo la tabla transformador
                .Include(m => m.Medidor.Transformador.BobinaIns)// traigo la tabla transformador
                .Include(m => m.Medidor.Transformador.BobinaIns.SelloIns)// traigo la tabla transformador
                .Include(m => m.Medidor.Transformador.BobinaRet)// traigo la tabla transformador
                .Include(m => m.Medidor.Transformador.BobinaRet.SelloRet)// traigo la tabla transformador
                .Include(m => m.Medidor.LecServicio)//traigo los datos de lec Servicio
                .Include(m => m.Medidor.LecServicio.Corriente)//traigo los datos de Corrientes
                .Include(m => m.Medidor.LecServicio.Trafo)//traigo los datos de medidor
                .Include(m => m.Medidor.LecServicio.Regleta)//traigo regleta
                .Include(m => m.Medidor.LecServicio.Medidor20)// medidor 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que en tu peticion con axios `axios.get("api/MedicionPrincipals/" , idMedicion)` es equivalente a esto `"api/MedicionPrincipals"` , por eso no llega el valor del id en tu controller de asp net core, pero cuando lo haces manualmente si hace la busqueda, intenta de esta manera: `axios.get("api/MedicionPrincipals/" + idMedicion)` o usando strings template de js

```
axios.get(`api/MedicionPrincipals/${idMedicion}`)
```

con eso deberia de funcionar, saludos.

Comment: hola amigo, no, la probe de las 2 maneras,       Actualizar(idMedicion) {
      let me = this;
      axios
        .get('api/MedicionPrincipals/${idMedicion}' )
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          me.medi = response.data;
         me.nise = me.medi.nise
      
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },

Comment: Actualizar(idMedicion) {
        let me = this;
        axios
          .get("api/MedicionPrincipals/" + me.idMedicion )
          .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            me.medi = response.data;
          me.nise = me.medi.nise
        
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      },                                      compañero, ya lo logre, tenia que raer el me.idMedicion que trae el vue. muchas gracias,